# Unity using "as" vs "GetComponent<>()"

Tags: unity, c#

Hello im new to unity and im learning raycast right now , after checking the documentation here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html , i got something that's confusing me , what is the difference between :

```
 MeshCollider themeshhit = thehit.collider as MeshCollider;
 //
 if (themeshhit == null) {
 Debug.Log (" | themeshhit == null ! | ");
 }   
 //
```

and :

```
 MeshCollider themeshhittwo =  thehit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ();
 //
 if (themeshhittwo == null) {
 Debug.Log (" | themeshhittwo == null ! | ");
 } 
 //
```

Both method is working correctly , but i want to know what is the difference between them , and i also want to know which one is better if comparing against speed , compatibility , and ability .

Edit : variable thehit is look similar to this

```
 RaycastHit thehit;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do what you want is the first one :

```
 MeshCollider theMeshHit = thehit.collider as MeshCollider;
```

In contrary to simple gameobjects `.collider` does not call `GetComponent` when using RaycastHit. The reference of the collider is stored in the object when the `Physics.Raycast` is called, and `.collider` is the getter to this collider.

The 2nd piece of code you tried calls a useless `.gameobject` make it slower.

TL; DR :

- `thehit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ();` : 1 call to `GetComponent` + 1 call to `.gameobject`
- `thehit.collider as MeshCollider` : 1 cast used

Comment: okay thanks for the warn but this is not answering my question , i still upvote it because this is important .

Comment: I edited my answer with additional information.

Comment: i disagree you said "using the as keyword is not needed" because its working ( and shorter )  , also i don't understand how i call  "GetComponent<>()" twice in my second code . **Edit** : maybe you can explain why i should not use "as" and tell me the difference between "as" and "GetComponent<>()"

Comment: Calling `GetComponent <MeshCollider>()` already returns a `MeshCollider` object, thus, you don't need to cast using the `as` keyword. I already said that `thehit.collider` is the (bad) shorthand to `thehit.GetComponent <Collider>`, thus, when you write `thehit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider> (); ` you call `GetComponent` twice.

Comment: okay that's clear enough ,  using "GetComponent<>()" is faster and shorter . but is there any special ability at each method ?

Comment: No, as far as I know. The components shorthands (`.collider`, `.transform`, ...)  may be removed in the future (Unity 6 I hope), the 2nd method you mentioned does not bring anything more, and the method I suggested is the faster, shorter and cleaner way to get the component of your entity.

Comment: Well, in fact, I realised I am totally wrong, my answer applies to a "simple" gameobject ! I think you won't be able to call `GetComponent` to a `RaycastHit` object ! >.<

Comment: edited your answer , please review again